# Angular2 pass attribute to class constructor

Tags: typescript, angular

How do I pass attributes from a parent component to their child components' class constructor in `Angular 2`?

Half of the mystery is figured out, as attributes can be passed to the view without problem.

### /client/app.ts

```typescript
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Example} from 'client/example';

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: `<p>Hello</p>
    <example [test]="someAttr"
      [hyphenated-test]="someHyphenatedAttr"
      [alias-test]="someAlias"></example>
    `,
  directives: [Example]
})
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.someAttr = "attribute passsed to component";
    this.someHyphenatedAttr = "hyphenated attribute passed to component";
    this.someAlias = "attribute passed to component then aliased";
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

### /client/example.ts

```typescript
import {Component, View, Attribute} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  properties: ['test', 'hyphenatedTest', 'alias: aliasTest']
})
@View({
  template: `
    <p>Test: {{test}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passsed to component -->
    <p>Hyphenated: {{hyphenatedTest}}</p>
    <!-- result: hyphenated attribute passed to component -->
    <p>Aliased: {{alias}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passed to component then aliased -->

    <button (click)="attributeCheck()">What is the value of 'this.test'?</button>
    <!-- result: attribute passed to component -->
  `
})
/*******************************************************************
* HERE IS THE PROBLEM. How to access the attribute inside the class? 
*******************************************************************/
export class Example {
  constructor(@Attribute('test') test:string) {
     console.log(this.test); // result: undefined
     console.log(test); // result: null
  }
  attributeCheck() {
    alert(this.test);
  }
}
```

To re-iterate:

> How can I access an **attribute inside the child component's class** passed in from the parent component?

[Repo](https://github.com/ShMcK/Angular2-Underderstanding/tree/master/props-attrs-test)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Updated to beta.1*

You can use [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html) for this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  inputs: ['test', 'hyphenatedTest', 'alias: aliasTest'],
  template: `
    <p>Test: {{test}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passsed to component -->
    <p>Hyphenated: {{hyphenatedTest}}</p>
    <!-- result: hyphenated attribute passed to component -->
    <p>Aliased: {{alias}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passed to component then aliased -->

    <button (click)="attributeCheck()">What is the value of 'this.test'?</button>
    <!-- result: attribute passed to component -->
  `
})
export class Example {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.test);
    this.attributeCheck();
  }

  attributeCheck() {
    alert(this.test);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to properties values in child component you can:

```
import {Component, View, Attribute} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  properties: ['test', 'hyphenatedTest', 'alias: aliasTest']
})
@View({
  template: `
    <p>Test: {{_test}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passsed to component -->
    <p>Hyphenated: {{_hyphenatedTest}}</p>
    <!-- result: hyphenated attribute passed to component -->
    <p>Aliased: {{_alias}}</p>
    <!-- result: attribute passed to component then aliased -->
  `
})
export class Example {
  _test: string;
  _hyphenatedTest: any; //change to proper type
  _alias: any; //change to proper type

  constructor() {
  }

  set test(test) {
    this._test = test;
  }

  set hyphenatedTest(hyphenatedTest) {
    this._hyphenatedTest = hyphenatedTest;
  }

 set alias(alias) {
    this._alias = alias;
  }

}
```

`set` method is run when the value of property changes. Value is passed to your local variable on which you can operate in component.

Important things:

- set method is always executed after constructor
- I don't know why but the name of parameter in `set` method must be same as name of this method (so it means it must be the same as name of property)

Comment: This is very helpful to know. Thank you! 

However, as the `set` method is run after the constructor, I still don't have access to `this.test` when the class is loaded. 

There must be a solution.

Comment: I've edited the solution above to show that the `@Attribute` way also sets `this.test`, however also after the constructor has loaded.

Comment: I was searching solution of this problem last week but nothing worked. I hope that it exists. `set` method is poor replacement - unfortunately it doesn't solve all problems.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I could potentially move my constructor code into the `set` block. It would actually work, but there must be a better way.